# Python/Anaconda - Is running the environment python executable different than activating the environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, miniconda, anaconda3

I have a simple query. I have two ways of running a python script in my virtual anaconda environment.

Alternative 1:

```
conda activate my_env
python3 my_python_script
```

Alternative 2:

```
~/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/python3 my_python_script
```

So, I don't understand what is the difference between these 2 alternatives. I understand that when activating the environment, "~/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin" is added to the PATH, but I don't know if something else happens. At least with the python scripts that I have tried there is no difference, but I would like to know in which cases it would be different.

Just in case, I've already seen "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50575330/what-is-the-difference-between-activating-an-anaconda-environment-and-running-it" but didn't understand the answer.

Answer (score 1):

my 2cent is that try running `~/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/python3 -m site` and see whether sys.path points to the site-packages in your conda environment. If so I would say there is practically no difference.

If not, then I will suspect while the python binary is using the conda env one, the site-packages however is not.

Comment: The output is exactly the same in both cases. So I think both alternatives are the same.

Answer (score 1):

The python interpreter will check the same directories when you run an `import` command. But to say that it therefore does not matter if you do

```
conda activate my_env
python my_python_script
```

or

```
~/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/python my_python_script
```

is too simplistic. The main difference is that `conda activate` modifies the `PATH` environment variable, which can become critical, even when running "simple" scripts. I'll try to elaborate on some cases where it might make a difference

On a linux machine, I can do

```
~/Software/miniconda3/envs/py37/bin/python -c "import numpy"
```

with no problem. But already on a windows machine, when I try something similar:

```
C:\Users\Florian\miniconda3\envs\py38\python.exe -c "import numpy"
```

I get a `DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath` error, whereas

```
conda activate py38
python -c "import numpy"
```

works without issue. So running any script that relies on numpy (or other modules that try yo load DLLs) fails, since detecting said DLLs relies on their path being in PATH, which they are after `conda activate`.

In case your python scripts are running any external tool (e.g. hrough `subprocess.popen`), then it might also be critical in case these tools are installed into the env, as they can be found through the PATH if you ahve done `conda activate`, but cannot be found if you have just run the python interpreter explicilty.